# Round up a value to the nearest power of 2 in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to round up a value to the next nearest power of 2 in a mysql query, so

```
select RoundUpToNearestPowerOfTwo(700) -- Should give 1024
```

I need this solution as part of a much larger query to generate and read some bitmask. Using custom stored functions is not an option, since I cannot use those in our production environment, so I'm looking for a smart way to do this inline in the query.

[Edit]
One possible way I can think of, is creating some enumerator, use a power in that, and choose the smallest value larger than my value:

```
  select
    min(BOUND)
  from
    (select 700 as VALUE) v
    inner join
      (select
        POW(2, @pow := @pow + 1) as BOUND
      from
        (select @pow := 0) x,
        MY_RANDOM_TABLE t
      ) x on x.BOUND > v.VALUE
```

But as you can tell, it's pretty verbose, so a leaner solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.

```
FLOOR(POW(2,CEIL(LOG2(1025))))
```

The CEIL and FLOOR cope with the boundary conditions correctly.

Comment: Is `FLOOR()` really needed here?

Comment: Very neat as well. But it seems you don't need `FLOOR` at all. After all, you already round the fractional results of `log2` and POW(2, N) should never have a fraction when N is integer.

Comment: FLOOR is not really needed. Call me a numerical noodge if you want, but I've been burned often enough by using defaults for double to integer conversion that I can hardly imagine not specifying it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select power(2, 1 + floor(log2(XXX)))
```

MySQL conveniently has the `log2()` function, which does most of the work.

EDIT:

I think this may be what you want:

```
select (case when floor(log2(XXX)) <> log2(XXX)
             then power(2, 1 + floor(log2(XXX)))
             else power(2, floor(log2(XXX)))
        end)
```

Or something like:

```
select power(2, 1 + floor(log2(XXX*0.999999)))
```

There is a boundary condition on actual powers of 2.

Comment: Very nice, sir. :) I will gladly accept this answer as soon as I can. Unless, of course, someone else will bring be an even more genius solution. ;) The first solution looks very lean, but indeed has the problem that an exact value of 1024 will result in 2048. I think that is not a problem for me, but if it turns out to be, I'll have the others as a fallback.

Comment: It turns out the boundary condition is due to `1 + floor`, which should be `ceil` instead.

Comment: @GolezTrol . . . Actually, the original query doesn't specify what to do in the boundary case and the sample code has `x.BOUND > v.VALUE` which suggests that `1 + floor()` is the equivalent code.  However, rounding say 16 to 32 in this case violates common sense.

Comment: You're right. I didn't define it properly. The sample was just some general idea that I hadn't fully tested yey. I must admit I didn't really think about the boundary condition and I don't think it matters much for my specific purpose. I mainly needed it, because I need to store multiple numbers in a big number to create some bit patters, so worst case, I would have an extra unused bit in that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server then you can try this...just change value in variable @value for any value to get the next nearest power of 2

```
declare @count int = 1
declare @value int = 700
while (@value <> 1)
BEGIN
    set @value = @value / 2
    set @count = @count + 1
END
select power(2, @count)
```